# SQL Server: Inserting a list of ints into a temporary table

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of IDs in a text file like this:

```
24641985 ,
24641980 ,
24641979 ,
24641978 ,
24641976 ,
24641974 ,
...
...
24641972 ,
24641971 ,
24641970 ,
24641968 ,
24641965)
```

There's tens of thousands of them.

Now I need to know which ids are in this list, that do not correspond to an ID in my table.

I guess I should put them into a temporary table, then say something like:

```
select theId 
  from #tempIdCollection
 where theId not in (select customerId from customers)
```

Problem is I don't know how to get them into the temp table!

Can anyone help? This doesn't have to be efficient. I've just got to run it once. Any solution suggestions welcome!

Thanks in advance!

-Ev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a table variable.  You declare it just like a regular variable.

```
declare @tempThings table (items int)
insert @tempThings values (1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's what I went with because I'm in such a hurry.

Comment: Hum, problem with insert @tempThings values (704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719);

Answer (score 3):

Have a "permanent temp" table, also known as an "inbox" table.  Just a simple tabled named something like "temp_bunchOfKeys".

Your basic sequence is:

1) Truncate temp_bunchOfKeys

2) BCP the text file into temp_bunchOfKeys

3) Your sql is then:

```
select theId 
  from Temp_BunchOfKeys
 where theId not in (select customerId from customers)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have to look more into BCP, which I've never heard of. Is it possible to BCP to a #tempTable?

Comment: I honestly don't know if you can BCP into a temp table, but I strongly suspect not, since the BCP command is run from the Command Line and establishes a connection, and there is nowhere in that sequence to establish a temp table.  A note about the BCP docs, they are scary looking but you ignore more or less all of it.  Just work out a BCP command that provides login id, db name, table name, and the file to suck in.  A few tries with the syntax usually gets you going.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with strings instead of integers, and solved it by using a split function (see code below) that returns a table variable with the list content. Modify the function to suit your purpose.

Example of how to call the function

```
create table #t (Id int, Value varchar(64))
insert into #t (Id, Value)
select Id, Item
from dbo.fnSplit('24641978, 24641976, ... 24641972, 24641971', ',')
/*Do your own stuff*/
drop table #t
```

Function

```
if object_id(N'dbo.fnSplit', N'TF') is not null
    drop function dbo.fnSplit
GO

create function dbo.fnSplit(@string varchar(max), @delimiter char(1))
returns @temptable table (Id int, Item varchar(8000))
as
begin
    -- NB! len() does a rtrim() (ex. len('2 ') = 1)
    if ( len( @string ) < 1 or @string is null ) return

    declare @idx int
    declare @slice varchar(8000)
    declare @stringLength int
    declare @counter int ; set @counter = 1

    set @idx = charindex( @delimiter, @string )

    while @idx!= 0
    begin
        set @slice = ltrim( rtrim( left(@string, @idx - 1)))
        set @slice = replace( replace(@slice, char(10), ''), char(13), '')
        insert into @temptable(Id, Item) values(@counter, @slice)

        -- To handle trailing blanks use datalength()
        set @stringLength = datalength(@string)
        set @string = right( @string, (@stringLength - @idx) )
        set @idx = charindex( @delimiter, @string )
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end

    -- What's left after the last delimiter
    set @slice = ltrim(rtrim(@string))
    set @slice = replace( replace(@slice, char(10), ''), char(13), '')
    insert into @temptable(Id, Item) values(@counter, @slice)

return
end
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can copy paste all those ids from text file to a excel file. Then use import from excel feature in the Sql server to create a table out of that excel file. Quite simple really. Let me know if you need more specific instructions.